# How to put the Digital Crown back to work with watchOS 4

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-4

I've got a watchkit app that makes use of the digital crown by setting

```
crownSequencer.delegate = self
crownSequencer.focus()
```

In the awake method of my interface controller that's implementing:

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WKCrownDelegate
```

In watchOS 3 my delegate Method was executed just fine:

```
// called when the crown rotates, rotationalDelta is the change since the last call (sign indicates direction).
func crownDidRotate(_ crownSequencer: WKCrownSequencer?, rotationalDelta: Double) {

    // do something important here...
}
```

After upgrading to watchos4, this functionality breaks.
A simple recompile and conversion to swift 4 didn't help.

Comment: I found that an interaction with some UI element will 'steal' the focus from the crownSequencer - might this be what is happening to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve this problem by simply moving the crownSequencer code to the willActivate method of my interface controller:

```
override func willActivate() {
    ...

    crownSequencer.delegate = self
    crownSequencer.focus()
}
```

It looks to me that something steals the focus in watchOS 4 (maybe something related to the spritekit I'm using?) if you set the focus too early.

Hope this saves some time for someone else!

Comment: Any idea how to replicate the issue?
My app works 90% of the time, then somewhere down the track when the app starts up, it stops detecting the crown rotation.  I want to consistently replicate it before I put in a fix so I know it's fixed.  Wondering what the trigger is.

Also wondering if didAppear would be a better place.  Currently I have it in awake().

Comment: Yes - didAppear is definitely better, since willAppear is not called alle the time. But even there I notice the same as you described: In 10% it still stops working :-/

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve it that simply.  I needed to add a delay to reestablish focus on the crown as follows:

-(void)delayDo{

```
self.crownSequencer.delegate=self;

[self.crownSequencer focus];
```

}

-(void)didAppear{

```
[self performSelector:@selector(delayDo) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```

}